# Solve $y=p\tan p+ \log (\cos p)$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

> Solve
> $$y=p\tan p+ \log (\cos p)$$
> Where $p=\dfrac {dy}{dx}$

Do you think this solution is correct ?

[image]

Just solved it. I think it's correct but needed expert's confirmation.
New here. Apologies for the tags.

Comment: I would think the solution should be $Y=f(x)$, i.e. an explicit solution in terms of $x$, whereas as written it's still in terms of $P=dY/dx$. (e.g solve for $Y$ in terms of $x$ from your $x=\tan(P)+C$ equation).

Comment: It's log (cos p)

Comment: @Alexey can it even be solved for that ?

Comment: Yes, I think your solution is correct even though it has an implicit form, nevertheless you have forgotten the solution which is possible to obtain by $p=0$ that is $y(x)=0$ for any $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution on parametric form is correct.

One can transform it on explicit form in putting $$p=\tan^{-1}(x-c)+k\pi$$ into the $y(p)$ equation :
$$y(x)=(x-c)\big(\tan^{-1}(x-c)+k\pi\big)+\ln\big(\cos(\tan^{-1}(x-c)+k\pi) \big)$$
or equivalently :
$$y(x)=(x-c)\big(\tan^{-1}(x-c)+k\pi\big)-\frac12\ln\big(1+(x-c)^2 \big)$$
We observe that for $x=c$ the result is $y=0$. Since $c$ is any constant, the solution $y=0$ for any $x$ is included in the above general solution.